# How can I send a direct message to a user after a certain interval in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a command in which the bot sends the author of the message a dm after a certain interval, say 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want this to be executed after a command has been sent:

```py
import asyncio # for the sleep statement

@bot.command()
async def messageme(ctx):
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await ctx.author.send("This is my DM to you!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Member.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.send)
- [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping)